# Elementwise Median of 3 matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, median

I have 3 matrices storing triplicate measurements in each matrix (matrix 1, measurement 1, matrix 2 measurement 2, .....)

They have the following structure:

```
> a1
            ACTIN       18S      TET1      TET2      TET3
Control 25.943441  22.62984      <NA> 34.063107 34.034756
Sample1  24.48504  20.04858      <NA>  32.37173 32.341072
Sample2 25.265867 19.680647 28.086248  33.76187  33.41289
Sample3 24.441484 18.146513      <NA> 32.811428  31.22825
> a2
            ACTIN       18S      TET1      TET2      TET3
Control 25.980696 22.393877      <NA> 34.548923   33.7815
Sample1 24.263775 20.073978  27.23082  32.27775 32.343292
Sample2  25.25487 19.680494 27.214449  33.70534  33.48968
Sample3  24.26332 18.108198      <NA> 32.769787  31.19895
> a3
            ACTIN       18S      TET1      TET2      TET3
Control 25.937397 22.429556 30.020935  33.98415 33.858604
Sample1  24.44776 20.090088 28.328804 32.317287 32.291912
Sample2 25.148333 19.537455      <NA>  33.83607   33.3961
Sample3 24.242998 18.335524      <NA> 32.788536 31.147346
```

I would like to create a new matrix with the medians of the 3 measurements.
Idealy with the 1st column staying the same. 
Giving `NA` if there is not a value (the Undetermined) is prefered

I would like to have a matrix with the medians, so something like this:

```
median(a1[i,j], a2[i,j], a2[i,j])
```

I tried the following:
2 for loops cycling over the arrays:

```
med<-matrix(NA, nrow(a1), ncol(a1))    
for(i in ncol(a1)){
      for(j in nrow(a1)){
        med[i,j]<-median(a1[i,j], a2[i,j], a2[i,j])
      }
    }
```

but this gives me values that are clearly not the median and I feel it is overly complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and reshape the resulting matrix. Assuming your data is initially a character matrix which I infer from `<NA>`, a reproducible solution would be like:

```
dat <- mapply(function(...) median(as.numeric(c(...))), a1, a2, a3)
# this gives a warning message but you can ignore this which comes up when it converts the character `NA` to numeric `NA`;
matrix(dat, nrow(a1), ncol(a1), dimnames = dimnames(a1))

#            ACTIN     X18S TET1     TET2     TET3
# Control 25.94344 22.42956   NA 34.06311 33.85860
# Sample1 24.44776 20.07398   NA 32.31729 32.34107
# Sample2 25.25487 19.68049   NA 33.76187 33.41289
# Sample3 24.26332 18.14651   NA 32.78854 31.19895
```

*Data*:

```
a1 <- structure(c("25.94344", "24.48504", "25.26587", "24.44148", "22.62984", 
"20.04858", "19.68065", "18.14651", "<NA>", "<NA>", "28.086248", 
"<NA>", "34.06311", "32.37173", "33.76187", "32.81143", "34.03476", 
"32.34107", "33.41289", "31.22825"), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(
    c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), c("ACTIN", 
    "X18S", "TET1", "TET2", "TET3")))

a2 <- structure(c("25.98070", "24.26377", "25.25487", "24.26332", "22.39388", 
"20.07398", "19.68049", "18.10820", "<NA>", "27.23082", "27.214449", 
"<NA>", "34.54892", "32.27775", "33.70534", "32.76979", "33.78150", 
"32.34329", "33.48968", "31.19895"), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(
    c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), c("ACTIN", 
    "X18S", "TET1", "TET2", "TET3")))

a3 <- structure(c("25.93740", "24.44776", "25.14833", "24.24300", "22.42956", 
"20.09009", "19.53746", "18.33552", "30.020935", "28.328804", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "33.98415", "32.31729", "33.83607", "32.78854", 
"33.85860", "32.29191", "33.39610", "31.14735"), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(
    c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), c("ACTIN", 
    "X18S", "TET1", "TET2", "TET3")))
```

Comment: Don't know what it gives me, but it is not the median: the first value is 18.5 for example, which is not possible

Comment: Well `matrix(mapply(function(...) median(as.numeric(c(...))), a1, a2, a3), nrow = nrow(a1), ncol = ncol(a1))` works on @Patrick's data. Besides your data has both characters and numeric and it is stored in a matrix which only accepts one type of data. And also it is difficult to reproduce your data by the format you gave. Usually `dput(a1)` etc is a good option. Keeping spaces in the column names is a bad practice. All these makes the problem hard to reproduce and people reluctant to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what's happening, but I get other values:  `dat <- mapply(function(...) median(as.numeric(c(...))), a1, a2, a3)
matrix(dat, nrow(a1), ncol(a1), dimnames = dimnames(a1))
        ACTIN  18S TET1 TET2 TET3
Control  18.5  6.5  6.5   NA  6.5
Sample1   6.5 18.5  6.5  6.5   NA
Sample2    NA  6.5 18.5  6.5  6.5
Sample3   6.5   NA  6.5 18.5  6.5`

Comment: Are you sure your data is as you have pasted and stated? Check `class(a1)` to see if they are actually matrix, instead of data frame.

Comment: If they are data frames, try this: `do.call(cbind, Map(function(...) mapply(function(...) median(c(as.numeric(as.character(...)))), ...), a1, a2, a3))`.

Comment: That's it. I am relatively new to R having problems to keep track how the different objects actually work

Answer (score 2):

You could first replace "Undetermined" by "NA" and you will automatically get an `NA`. I don't want to type in all those numbers, so I just used 1 through 5 but it should work for any numbers.

```
a1 <- data.frame(c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), 1, 2, c("Undetermined", "Undetermined", 3, "Undetermined"), 4, 5) 
a2 <- data.frame(c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), 1, 2, c("Undetermined", 3, 3, "Undetermined"), 4, 5) 
a3 <- data.frame(c("Control", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"), 1, 2, c(3, 3, "Undetermined", "Undetermined"), 4, 5) 
names(a1) <- names(a2) <- names(a3) <- c("Sample", "CT ACTIN", "CT 18S", "CT TET1", "CT TET2", "CT TET3")
a1[a1 == "Undetermined"] <- NA
a2[a2 == "Undetermined"] <- NA
a3[a3 == "Undetermined"] <- NA

med <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(a1), ncol = ncol(a1))
for (i in 1:nrow(a1)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(a1)){
  med[i, j] <- median(c(a1[i, j], a2[i, j], a3[i, j]))
  }
}

med <- data.frame(a1[, 1], med)
names(med) <- c("Sample", "CT ACTIN", "CT 18S", "CT TET1", "CT TET2", "CT TET3")
```

Comment: Please, post your code as a reproducible one. You are not new. Why are you making this type of mistake?

Comment: Replacing the text with 'NA' is not a problem. I want this script to work for matrices no matter where the undetermined is and no matter what the dimensions of the matrices are (they will be all the same dimensions though)

Comment: @user2100721 Which part is not reproducible?

Comment: Remove `+` & `>`. Don't paste the console output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datasets are in the form in which you posted them before your edits:

```
> a1
#    Sample CT ACTIN   CT 18S      CT TET1  CT TET2  CT TET3
#1: Control 25.94344 22.62984 Undetermined 34.06311 34.03476
#2: Sample1 24.48504 20.04858 Undetermined 32.37173 32.34107
#3: Sample2 25.26587 19.68065    28.086248 33.76187 33.41289
#4: Sample3 24.44148 18.14651 Undetermined 32.81143 31.22825
```

You could use `mget()` to retrieve the objects matching `a[[:digit:]]` in your environment and `bind_rows()` them together:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "a[[:digit:]]")))
```

Then use `na_if()` to replace `"Undetermined"` by  `NA`, transform all columns but `Sample` to numeric, and compute the `median()` using `summarise_each()`

```
dat %>%
  na_if("Undetermined") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), -Sample) %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(median(., na.rm = TRUE)), -Sample)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#   Sample CT ACTIN   CT 18S  CT TET1  CT TET2  CT TET3
#    <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 Control 25.94344 22.42956 30.02094 34.06311 33.85860
#2 Sample1 24.44776 20.07398 27.77981 32.31729 32.34107
#3 Sample2 25.25487 19.68049 27.65035 33.76187 33.41289
#4 Sample3 24.26332 18.14651       NA 32.78854 31.19895
```